# Monodroid - EditText input method won't accept numbers

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-edittext, android-2.3-gingerbread, android-input-method

I am having some very strange problems with the EditText control in Mono for Android. My solution is targeting 2.3 and I am debugging on a T Mobile VivaCity. Here is my AXML for the EditText

```axml
<EditText
    android:inputType="text"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ctl_searchText" />
```

When I show the View containing the EditText the keyboard automatically appears, this is not a problem. The problem is I can't enter any numbers by tapping the numbers on the keyboard, the only way I can get a number to show in the text field is if I hold the key down and chose the number from a context menu. Although once I've entered a number in using this method I'm then not able to delete it. I've tried all sorts of input methods and had a look for similar issues in SO to no avail. Does this sound like an issue with the device? Or is there something glaringly obvious I'm not doing in the code/AXML?

**== EDIT ==**

I think I've narrowed the problem down, it has something to do with the KeyPress event handler used on the EditText. As the EditText represents a search field I have added the attribute android:singleLine="true" to stop the return key from adding an extra line and instead say "Done". When I add a KeyPress event handler to the control this is when it stops me from entering numbers, but without the handler it begins to function normally again. Here is what I have:

```axml
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ctl_searchText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:singleLine="true" />
```

```cs
EditText ctl_searchText = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.ctl_searchText);

ctl_searchText.KeyPress += (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e) => 
{
    if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, ctl_searchText.Text, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
};
```

With this code I cannot enter numbers into the text field, but I can enter letters. When I remove the event handler it works again, allowing me to enter all characters. I'm going to carry on investigating, this is very strange.

Comment: What happens when you try in the emulator?

Comment: Running it on the API_10 allows me to enter letters with the input type as "text" but not numbers. I tried android:inputType="text|number" but that just allowed me to enter numbers and not letters. There must be an input type that allows for all characters, but somehow I can't find it >_<

Comment: did you managed to solve your problem?

Answer (score 5):

Please cheack that you doesn't use [OnKeyListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnKeyListener.html). If yes just check that onKey (View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) method return True if the listener has consumed the event, false otherwise. In your case it something like this:

```
   ctl_searchText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER){ 
                //do smth
                return true;
            }
            return fasle;
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

Try adding an else stating that e.Handled = false;

Your code will then look like:

```
ctl_searchText.KeyPress += (object sender, View.KeyEventArgs e) => 
{
    if (e.Event.Action == KeyEventActions.Down && e.KeyCode == Keycode.Enter)
    {
        Toast.MakeText (this, ctl_searchText.Text, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
        e.Handled = true;
    }
    else
    { 
        e.Handled = false;
    }
};
```